# Sencha touch production build errors

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-touch, command, sencha-cmd

Using touch 2.1.0 and Cmd 3.1.2.342

Whilst trying to create a production version of my sencha app, I get the following error:

> [WRN] C1003: Unsupported Ext.define syntax -- C:\wamp\www\touch-2.1.0\axis\nativ
>   e\appname\touch\src\fx\TimingFunctions.js:109
>
> [ERR] C2008: Requirement had no matching files (Ext.fx.TimingFunctions) -- C:\wa
>   mp\www\touch-2.1.0\axis\native\appname\touch\src\fx\Abstract.js:959
>
> [ERR] The following error occurred while executing this line:
>   C:\wamp\www\touch-2.1.0\axis\native\appname.sencha\app\build-impl.xml:165:

It seems to me that it is saying a file called fx/TimingFunctions.js is required by fx/Abstract.js but cannot be found. However, this can't be what it means as the file exists in that folder.

The command I am using is:

> sencha app build production

Line 109 of TimingFunctions.js looks like this:
`Ext.define('Ext.fx.TimingFunctions', Ext.apply({
        singleton: true,...`

One solution is to change line 109 of TimingFunctions.js from:

`Ext.define('Ext.fx.TimingFunctions', Ext.apply({`

to:

`Ext.define('Ext.fx.TimingFunctions', {`

and change line 136 of the same file from:

`}, EasingPrototype));`

to:

`}, EasingPrototype);`

This then allows the build to go ahead.

However, when I then view the production app in the web browser, it freezes and I get the following error

> Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'call' process sencha-touch-all-debug.js:6767
>
> (anonymous function) process sencha-touch-all-debug.js:6774
>
> (anonymous function) sencha-touch-all-debug.js:6779
>
> Ext.apply.onBeforeCreated sencha-touch-all-debug.js:5196
>
> process sencha-touch-all-debug.js:5262
>
> process sencha-touch-all-debug.js:5268
>
> process sencha-touch-all-debug.js:5268
>
> process sencha-touch-all-debug.js:5268
>
> Ext.apply.process sencha-touch-all-debug.js:5272
>
> Ext.Class.ExtClass sencha-touch-all-debug.js:5183
>
> Ext.ClassManager.create sencha-touch-all-debug.js:6725
>   Ext.apply.define sencha-touch-all-debug.js:7407
>
> (anonymous function) TimingFunctions.js?_dc=1379403994382:109
>
> (anonymous function) TimingFunctions.js?_dc=1379403994382:138

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a spelling mistake in the files fx/Abstract.js and fx/TimingFunctions.js
Actually, it's not a spelling mistake - more like a grammatical error.

Abstract.js calls a function in TimingFunctions.js. in Abstract.js it is referred to as `EasingMap`, where as in TimingFunctions.js it is called `easingMap`