# Sencha build error when viewed in browser

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-cmd

I have finally managed to create a production build of my sencha web app using Cmd 3.10.2.342 and touch 2.2.1

All my bespoke files are included and deltas are created as one would expect. However, when I run it in the browser, it stalls at the loading view. Console log says:

> TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'h.call(w,w)')

I have traced the error to `Ext.application({...` in app.js.
I have tried the following changes, but still get errors:

1. new Ext.application({...
2. Ext.Application({...
3. new Ext.Application({...

How can I rectify this?

When I generate an apk file, I do not have this problem

In my production app.js, I found this
`if(!s){a.set(i,w);if(h){h.call(w,w)}a.triggerCreated(i);return}`

I don't really know what it does. I have tried deleting it etc, but it just the gives other errors instead

Comment: Use a debugger and check out what kind of object h actually is.  Put the debugger keyword in that if block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I traced this back to issues/conflicts with `itemId` and `id` where sencha was telling me that a component already existed and should be destroyed.

Solved it by removing `id` and `itemId` and used `cls` instead